# How do you reopen a ride after a crash in RollerCoaster Tycoon?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I realize this is an old game, but it's fun to pull out every once in awhile.  However, I've found that I never make it very far into the game because I'll end up crashing one or more roller coasters on a particular level.

It doesn't seem to be avoidable.  The crashes just happen eventually, even if your maintenance worker is checking it every 10 minutes.  Every time this has happened, I can't recover or re-open the coaster after it's fixed.  All I can do is delete the entire roller coaster, which can be costly and very annoying.

Is there any way (without using a cheat) to avoid the crash or recover after it?

Comment: Totally thought this was about not being able to recover money after a crash because nobody wants to ride it. Maybe a word besides "recover" would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try switch to the red flag **and** click the red flag again, It worked for me in R.C.T.2 but I am sure it should work in the first version too.

Comment: Yes, exactly, had this thought some time after posting my answer. Pressing once stops, pressing a second time resets the ride. Deleting my answer, this one is the correct one.

Comment: Added bonus: you can do this _before_ the ride crashes (pause every time you get a "broken down" message, then go see if it's a station brake failure).

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to avoid a crash is to place brakes before the station platform. Also, it's best to have a mechanic that fixes only that ride. If your roller coaster crashes, double-click the stop light to reset it. This will reopen it, but more than likely no one will want to go on it because "It isn't safe." Best thing to do is to save frequently andd just load a file after it crashes.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Phillip! I think that guests' fear of the coaster will go down, over time. In the near term, you might have to cut ride admission pretty severely to get any return from it.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Shek's answer, your coaster will suffer from reduced popularity because the guests will see it as unsafe. Frankly, the only way to get back up to your pre-crash numbers on it is to delete it and rebuild it. Fortunately, it's easy to save the coaster, delete it, and then build it from the save file. It will cost you money, since you're "selling" the original coaster, which has depreciated in value, but as a side benefit, you do get a new installation, which means the coaster will be more reliable.

Comment: This is not actually doable in many cases where you have underground rails. Actually, I've experienced a couple of crashed before; the best way to deal with them in the long run is simply to reset the coaster, fix anything that might have caused the crash, and then reopen it. With the time, as said by Raven, people will come and see it as safe again. You can cut entrance or run ads to make it faster.

Comment: Instead of deleting the entire coaster, just modify it so that it must receive a new test rating. The guests forget it was the crash coaster. Example: Change a straight track into a photo section. Now the coaster is "new".

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites - Not true. I edited a whole portion of my rollercoaster and people are still complaining about it "not being safe" just because "a few dozen people" "died" on it "a few months ago". Wimps if you ask me...

Comment: Strange I don't have that experience. I'm only familiar with the actual original versions of the game though... maybe whatever version that's on Steam or whatever these days is different.

Answer (score 2):

On RCT Deluxe, I just had a crash on a roller coaster where 32 people died.

I fixed the cause of the crash and then I made the price of the ride free. After a while I did a marketing campaign for the ride and it recovered, no thoughts about it being unsafe anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I happen to experience brake fails alot in Rct. In rct2 in a very lower rate, but it still exists though...

What you could do to PREVENT crashing:

- Use only one train per coaster
- However brakes fail with this kind of malfunctioning, the main brakes (used   to get a train to 0 speed before the station, then letting it go again) DO work, but since they can only brake the train for a small amount of speed, make sure your car goes slow enough to be stopped by this small piece of rails.
- Eventually, making the train move at a speed lower than 18mph might make the train hit a waiting train at the station without any explosion problems.
- Make sure your ride is long enough, so the mechanician has enough time to fix the brakes meanwhile.
  *Note: Make sure a train won't get stuck between two hills because of lacking speed, as this makes your coaster still crash.

When It DID happen, you can choose from any already mentioned solution in different comments, or just keep the coaster removed and make a more popular one.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had brakes before the station and this failed. All breaks actually fail. Therefore, the safest way is to put in 1 train only. That way you know that it'll never crash. The ride that does not crash is the crazy mouse ride.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to simply wait it out - the number  of guests complaining decreases relatively quickly over time and it isn't long before the ride is popular again. Maybe an ingame month or so.